# Start IMDb iOS app through safari - does it accept commands?

Tags: html, ios, browser, command

I noticed it's possible to start the IMDb app on an iOS device through safari by putting imdb:// into a simple HTML anchor. Does this accept any commands? I would like to open a movie through the browser in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IMDB url scheme, as of version 2.0, supports the following commands:

Keyword:

```
imdb:///find?q=frankenstein
```

Movie id:

```
imdb:///title/tt0021884/
```

Name (author, actor, cast) id:

```
imdb:///name/nm0000472/
```

Also, in version 2.1:

```
imdb:///showtimes
imdb:///title/tt0021884/cinemashowtimes
imdb:///boxoffice
imdb:///chart/moviemeter
imdb:///chart/starmeter
imdb:///chart/top
imdb:///chart/bottom
imdb:///chart/tv
imdb:///feature/comingsoon
imdb:///feature/bestpicture
imdb:///feature/tvrecaps
imdb:///feature/borntoday
```

(source: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes, but the site is broken right now)